# Definition of an End Block

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, definition

Can someone explain to me what is an End Block in graph theory. I can not find an exact definition for this.

Comment: It’s always useful to tell people in what context you are seeing terminology.

Comment: In particular, specific usages, in context, are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This definition I was referring to is Graph Theory.
I understood the correct definition. An end-block of G is a block with a single cut-vertex (a cut-vertex in a graph G is a vertex whose removal increases the number of connected components of G).

Answer (score 0):

Consider a partition of a finite set of natural numbers. Then the end block should be the partition block containing the set's biggest number.

E. g. for {{2, 9,  8}, {3, 1}}, the end block is {2, 9, 8}, since it contains the highest item 9 of the partitioned set {1, 2, 3, 8, 9}.

Comment: This *probably* has nothing to do with the question, since no graph theory is involved. Of course, since the question doesn't give any context, we can't be sure.

Comment: You are right. In the script ,,Free probability" of Roland Speicher, there are partition visualzations with graphs (to be more precise: forests), maybe @Kanchana thought of this by mentioning graph theory, but we simply do not know.